# App::setLocale($locale) in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

In my application i have three possible users

1. Guest
2. Logged in user
3. Admin user

I want to allow users to change their language. After looking at the i18n docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization , i found this function

`App::setLocale($locale);`

If i allow all the three group of users to be able to execute `App::setLocale($locale);` , will the the language of the entire site change or its just the language of that session?.

I want the admin to be able to change the language of the entire site, the logged in user to be able to choose his or her language and the guest to be able to set the language he or she prefers.

Will the function `App::setLocale($locale);` be of help to do what i want?.

Finally, urls like this are common `example.com/en/welcome`, `example.com/fr/welcome`

Does the en and fr mean i have to write extra routes to cater for the en - english and fr -french?.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer; someone will soon. `App::setLocale` changes the current request only

Answer (score 0):

You can add column inside the users table for their locals, and use `App::setLocale($locale);` for each process, or retrieve the user's local to return the response with the needed language, like `$data->translate($user->locale)->name` .. etc